# Kotlin how to create layout for galaxy z fold2

Tags: android, kotlin, samsung-galaxy

I recently bought a Samsung galaxy fold 2 and i am having issue with the layout of my app, nothing fit to the Fold size, the front size is not a regular size because it's taller but less wide. In deep everything that was on the right size of my app are half cut. And when i open the big inside screen it's doesn't respond to the sw600 criteria so the constraints are also not apply...

I would like to know if have to create layout with a certain size specially for the galaxy fold? In this case what are those size and how can i create it ? or if there is an other way to handle Fold size i would like to ear it.

Note that i also saw multiples application than doesn't take the full screen of the device and i got some black stripes on the sides, so maybe handle fold screen is not that easy...

Comment: did you found which custom layout could be support?